# QWidget:: paintEvent() - objects drawn with QPainter are clipped

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, drawing

I have simple Qt Widgets Application. I call update (rect) in mouseMoveEvent(). I call drawArc() and drawRect() in the paintEvent(). Function drawArc() draws the circle little bit smaller then rect and drawRect() draws event->rect(). They are drawn at mouse positions from mouseMoveEvent(). So I want to have app, where the circle, and square follow the cursor. I have such app but there is problem. The circle and square seem to be drawn at correct position, but they are clipped somehow. I've even enlarged the update rect by 100px but the clipping is still there. You can see it in the attached image. The code is below and also on the GitHub. I use Qt 5.15.1.

```
 void ScribbleArea::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
        mousePos = event->pos();
        int enlargement = 100;
        int size = 129+enlargement;
        QRect r = QRect(mousePos.x()-size/2,mousePos.y()-size/2,size,size);
        update(r);
}

void ScribbleArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    
    int size = 129;
    QRect arcRect = QRect(mousePos.x()-size/2,mousePos.y()-size/2,size,size);
    
    painter.drawArc(arcRect,0,16*360);
    painter.drawRect(event->rect().adjusted(10,10,-10,-10));
}
```

The entire code is on GitHub: https://github.com/AlessandroFilipepi/QtDrawingExampleIssue (Don't worry, it is short).

[image: Clipped brush]

Thank for help.

Comment: What if you update the whole widget, i.e. call `update()` function without parameters?

Comment: I tried that. It works but it is inefficient for my real app. Update whole widget takes too much time.

Comment: I think the problem is that you update rather the current area and not the "previous" one. Therefore you got these leftovers. You could also try to extend the updating region if updating the whole widget is slow.

Comment: I've edited my question an I've provided better image. Leftovers are caused by simplicity of code. It works in my real app. I want to know, why the parts of bottom and right edges of my "brush" are clipped. It is marked with red in the image.

Comment: I can confirm the issue with MSYS + Qt 5.15.2: https://imgur.com/a/J7ZnxiM

Comment: Also with wsl2 + Ubuntu 20.04 + VcXsrv + Qt 5.12.8: https://imgur.com/a/oT4oNM1